# How to apply jUnit test on a void method

Tags: testing, methods, junit, void

i have this class

```
@Value("${norsys.loadfile.directory}")
private String chemin;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody()
public void loadVideoFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        Files.copy(Paths.get(chemin, fileName), response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }
}
```

I dont know how to apply a JUnit test to keep coverage high, I hope that you can give me an idea, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use Mockito http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html to test classes which have heavyweight dependencies.  Using a mock HttpServletResponse class you could verify that the status code is set appropriately for your failure/success cases.

You're going to run into some problems with the use of those static methods.

Instead of

```
Files.copy(Paths.get(chemin, fileName), response.getOutputStream());
```

You could use a non-static class, which you could then mock

```
class ResourceCopier {
   public void copy(String dir, String file, OutputStream os) {
     Files.copy(Paths.get(dir, file), os);
   }
}
```

Your main class uses

```
private ResourceCopier resourceCopier;

public void loadVideoFile(....) {
   resourceCopier.copy(chemin, fileName, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

And in your test class you create your primary object, create a Mock of ResourceCopier and HttpServletResponse and use @InjectMocks to inject them to your primary object.
You can then use Mockito's verify() method to make sure the right things have happened (like response.setStatus called with 404 code)